# Deleting duplicate values (depending on second condition) from raster attribute table?

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, hydrology

How can I automaticly delete rows from a raster attribute table if the value of a specific column appears twice or more? For example my attribute table (below) shows in the column "Streamlink" the value 22 twice, now I want to keep the row with the maximum value in column "FLA_FLD666" and delete the smaller one. The best would be a arcpy solution.

[image: attribute Table]

Comment: The raster attribute table reflects the values present in the raster. Therefore, to eliminate a row you need to eliminate the value which causes the row. The `Con` function of Spatial Analyst can accomplish this. Python coding questions here are expected to include code, so I suggest you use the documentation and attempt this on your own, then if you have trouble, include that code in this Question.

Comment: I just used this code: Combined_Raster=Combine([Stream_Link,Flowaccumulation_Field_Raster]) to accomplish this table from two rasters I had.

Comment: Please **edit the question** to include any information you want potential answerers to consider.

Comment: I don't know what more Information are necessary. I don't think that I could accomplish this with the con tool because con doesn't know if a cell value is the same like one which was already processed before. I guess I have to work with RasterToNumPyArray, right?

Comment: Working on raster table can be tricky sometimes. Can be done, but simplest solution convert it to polygons, transfer attributes if necessary. Sort by second field, descending, delete duplicates using first field